# Overlay in google Maps, Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have the next problem: 
I want to put overlays in a mapView of googleMaps. I load the coordinates from a data server, then, I convert it to intE6 type. But when I put the GeoPoint in the map, it appear in other site, I try to put other points and the distance between points is good but they are displaced to other site. I think that the problem probably is the map configuration but I dont know where because I checked the coordinates of these points and are good and time ago it worked with other coordinates.

Thanks for your reply :)

I check it and the conversion is good:

```
float latitude = (float) json_data.getDouble("latitude");
float longitude = (float) json_data.getDouble("longitude");

Log.d("POINT",(int)(latitude*1E6)+" "+ (int)((longitude*1E6)));

GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int)(latitude*1E6), (int)(longitude*1E6));

Log.d("POINT", ""+p.getLatitudeE6()+" "+p.getLongitudeE6());
```

SOLVED: My fault, it works properly, there was other error in my code

Comment: Please post the part of your code where you convert the latitude and longitude, create the `GeoPoint` and add the point to the map.

Comment: My fault, it works properly, there was other error in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: My fault, it works properly, there was other error in my code.